What are all of the haram industries that I should avoid as a muslim entrepreneur? And are the vast majority of industries halal?
I am a muslim who wants to become a successful entrepreneur. But I feel like everything is haram. Am I wrong?

List questions hardly fit our stack exchange policies. It is better to ask about a specific topic. Since industries and professions change over time, it makes more sense to ask when in doubt. Or alternatively, ask what clues indicate a profession or industry that might be haram instead. Please make use of the "edit" link and re-phrase your question.
